# qml: Error: SSL Sockets are not supported on this platform

Tags: qt, ssl, websocket, qml

I'm currently trying to get [this](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/texmaker_v5.0.2/qt57/doc/qtwebsockets/qtwebsockets-qmlwebsocketclient-example.html)
`WebSocket` example working. I believe I get it rendering correctly but I get "qml: Error: SSL Sockets are not supported on this platform." When it tries to connect to the `WebSocket`. Any idea about what I can do to fix this?

I'm using Desktop `Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 64bit`

edit: The code I'm using is one of the built-in examples for Qt: qmlwebsocketclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't install OpenSSL by default like Linux. I found this the best way of installing OpenSSL to solve the problem.

1. Make sure OpenSSL toolkit is installed through Qt. This can be done through the `Qt Maintenance Tool`.
2. Set the environment variables to that install.
   -Add a new system variable named `OPENSSL_CONF` with the path to the openssl.cnf file. mine from a default install was `C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64\openssl.cnf`
   -Add the openssl bin to the system variable `Path`. Mine from a default install was `C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64\bin`

You can check if the path variable has been set correctly by opening a CMD and printing the version with openssl version. *This will print correctly even if the OPENSSL_CONF path is wrong*, but if correct the error should go away inside Qt.

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is **windows** you should install [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

[image]

and also be sure that you were installed `OpenSSL` libraries

[image]

Comment: I'm concerned about the security of the OpenSSL install that you linked. Is there a more secure alternative, or why should I trust the security of the source.

Comment: @sam.hay you need to install `OpenSSL` on your OS from **whatever you like**, and also you need the `OpenSSL toolkit` and check that you install it from Qt `MaintenanceTool` and these will solve your issue :)